# Why do I get an Error in using RWEKA package

Tags: r, rweka

I used the RWEKA and suddenly when I use:

```
> require("RWeka")
```

I get the following error:

```
Loading required package: RWeka
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘RWekajars’ 3.9.1-3 is already loaded, but >= 3.9.3.1 is required
```

Comment: It would appear the RWekajars is too old. Try updating only this package.

Comment: I tried to reinstall it> install.packages("RWekajars")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aw/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkvLHqS\file146c19693a', reason 'No such file or directory'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkvLHqS

Comment: Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\aw\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkvLHqS/libloc_190_7bc54c19.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection

Comment: Close all your R sessions and try again. Something might be holding onto  those jars.

Comment: I closed it, reinstalled all packages and I still get:

Comment: > require("RWeka")
Loading required package: RWeka
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWeka', details:
  call: .jnew("weka.core.WekaPackageManager")
  error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/packageManagement/PackageManager